# как отделить дату от времени C#

Tags: c#

помогите нужно от текста оставить только время (час/мин/сек) и вывести на консоль
пример :
30.01.2014 10:32:44 36324 36324 36324 36324 2
получается:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    DateTime mydatatime = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 19));

   Console.WriteLine("{0}", mydatatime);

   counter++;
}
```

В итоге получится

НО мне надо только время , а у меня дата и время

Comment: Console.WriteLine("{0}", mydatatime.ToLongTimeString() )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Укажите конкретный формат при выводе, например

```
Console.WriteLine(mydatatime.ToString("H:mm:ss"));
```

Полная справка по форматированию даты и времени: [Строки настраиваемых форматов даты и времени](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: а прокатит когда я открываю в файле

Comment: нет не прокатило он выводит на консоль время которое сейчас

Comment: @ильявитюк ну так подставьте вместо DateTime.Now свое время из файла - mydatatime

Comment: все сделал так где вы дали ссылку:

Comment: Console.WriteLine(  mydatatime.ToString("H:mm:ss"));

Comment: спасибо огромное